# Catch No-Internet-Connection Errors in django

Tags: django, sockets, email

Am currently using django to send emails, but the thing is that, when I am working on the local host without internet connection and I try to send an email. I get `[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo` failed which is understandable. The thing is that I want to know whether there is a way to catch errors as such so that I can manage them properly ?. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this where you are calling the sendmail function.

```
import socket

try:
   ...
except socket.gaierror:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to send an email and then catch the error for the local host without internet connection case, simply don't try to send an email during development.  You could use the `django.settings.DEBUG` option to determine whether an email should be sent.

Here's an example of how you could route emails to a file for testing or when running without an internet connection.

```
from django.core import mail
from django import settings
import tempfile

# Change SAVE_EMAIL_TO_FILE to be appropriate for your setup.  It could
# be based on settings.DEBUG or some other indication that you're running
# without an internet connection.
SAVE_EMAIL_TO_FILE = settings.DEBUG

def my_send_mail(*args, **kwargs):
    if SAVE_EMAIL_TO_FILE:
        # No emails during development.  Save to a file instead.
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as email_file:
            email_file.write("{args}\n{kwargs}\n".format(
                args=str(args),
                kwargs=str(kwargs)))
    else:
        # Production environment.
        mail.send_mail(*args, **kwargs)
```

This has the benefit that you will always get an exception on a production machine or during development on an internet connected machine if an email cannot be sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:

except Exception, e:
    code = '000'
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        code = e.code
        msg = 'No message returned from the server'
    if hasattr(e, 'msg'):
        msg = e.msg
    messages.error(
        request,
            'Error connecting to server. ERROR: {0} {1}'.format(code, msg)
    return ''
```